# Сортировка Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Подскажите как отсортировать записи по произвольному числовому полю, но что бы если поле не содержит ни какого значения, то сортировка была бы например по ID или дате модификации. При сортировке по числовому значению meta_value_num столкнулся с такой проблемой, если значение в поле отсутствует или они одинаковые, то при каждой перезагрузке страницы записи не имеющие этого значения выводятся рандомно, если использовать meta_value то сортировка не логичная. 
Вот код для сортировки по произвольному полю

```
'posts_per_page' => 9,
'post_type'         => 'catalog',
'meta_key'          => 'number',
'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
'order'             => 'ASC',
'paged'          => $paged,
```

Подскажите как сделать сортировку по ID, но если есть произвольное поле то выводить такие посты в списке выше и в соответствии со значением поля.

Пример: в скобках значение произвольного поля

1. Пост id 5 (1)
2. Пост id 2 (2)
3. Пост id 1 ()
4. Пост id 3 ()
5. Пост id 4 ()
6. Пост id 6 ()
7. ....

---

Попробовал объединить в один запрос, запрос обрабатывается невероятно долго и результат не тот((

```
    'posts_per_page' => 9,
    'post_type'         => 'catalog',
    'meta_key'          => 'number',
    'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    'number_yes' =>  array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'key' => 'number',
                        'compare' => 'EXISTS',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key' => 'number',
                        'value' => ' ',
                        'compare' => '!='
                    ),
                    'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
                    ),

    'number_none' =>     array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'key' => 'number',
                        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key' => 'number',
                        'value' => '',
                        'compare' => '='
                    ),
                        'orderby'   => 'id',
                    ),

     'orderby' => array( 'number_yes' => 'DESC', 'number_none' => 'ASC' ),
),
    'paged'          => $paged,
```

Помогите сделать правильный вывод

Answer (score 1):

А сделайте два запроса с последовательным выводом. Первый с исключением пустых **`meta_value`**:

```
'posts_per_page' => 9,
'post_type'      => 'catalog',
'meta_key'       => 'number',
'meta_value'     => ' ',
'meta_compare'   => '!=',
'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
'order'          => 'ASC',
'paged'          => $paged,
```

И следом второй, исключая не пустые **`meta_value`**:

```
'posts_per_page' => 9,
'post_type'      => 'catalog',
'meta_key'       => 'number',
'meta_value'     => '',
'meta_compare'   => '=',
'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
'order'          => 'ASC',
'paged'          => $paged,
```

Не проверял =)

Answer (score 1):

Если сделать два запроса:
Выводим записи с произвольным полем

```
'posts_per_page' => 9,
'post_type'         => 'catalog',
'meta_key'          => 'number',
'meta_query' => array(
        array(
        'key' => 'number',
        'value' => '',
        'compare'   => '='
        )),
'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
'order'             => 'DESC',
'paged'          => $paged,
```

и следом записи без произвольного поля, но с сортировкой по id

```
    'posts_per_page' => 9,
'post_type'         => 'catalog',
'meta_key'          => 'number',
'meta_query' => array(
        array(
        'key' => 'number',
        'value' => '',
        'compare'   => '!='
        )),
'orderby'        => 'ID',
'order'             => 'DESC',
'paged'          => $paged,
```

только проблема в том что:

1. Два цикла
2. Если у нас вдруг попадут поля с одинаковыми значениями они будут выводится рандомно

Собственно вопрос как исключить рандомность вывода записей, при одинаковых значениях произвольных полей?